# Reading double from text file in assets, with scanner without buffered reader

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a text file inside the assets folder, directory is main/src/assets/socso.txt, and what happen is when i trying to read it, there are error occur. I read a lot of other question, which include one that whr to place to text file, and I am very sure that I did it correctly, and most of the example uses buffered reader which I don't want so I modify it but still occur error. What I trying to do is use scanner to read double data type from the text file word by word, and hence should not be using buffered reader. Below are some of my code had been used:

```
InputStreamReader sc = new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("socso.txt"));
Vector v = new Vector();
Iterator i = v.iterator();
String llimit;
while((llimit = sc.toString()) != null)
{
    Socso s = new Socso();
    s.setLowerlimit(Double.parseDouble(llimit));
    s.setUpperlimit(Double.parseDouble(sc.toString()));
    s.setEmployershares(Double.parseDouble(sc.toString()));
    s.setEmployeeshares(Double.parseDouble(sc.toString()));
    s.setType2(Double.parseDouble(sc.toString()));

    v.add(s);
}

sc.close();
//when I run this, I can;t even run as error occur
```

**Another version**

```
//InputStream is = resources.getAssets().open("socso.txt"); (When I use this it appears as error too)
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(socso.txt); //(use this appear FileNotFoundException)
Scanner sc = new Scanner(is);
Vector v = new Vector();
Iterator i = v.iterator();
while(sc.hasNext())
{
    Socso s = new Socso();
    s.setLowerlimit(sc.nextDouble());
    s.setUpperlimit(sc.nextDouble());
    s.setEmployershares(sc.nextDouble());
    s.setEmployeeshares(sc.nextDouble());
    s.setType2(sc.nextDouble());

    v.add(s);
}
```

I had also tried AssetManager from another question, but the answer just did not answer my question as there are error occur on the context syntax, and I can't even run it.

Comment: Are you using this code from a fragment or from an activity?

Comment: "I have a text file inside the assets folder" -- then use `open("socso.txt")` on an `AssetManager`. An asset is a file on your development machine, not on the device, so `FileInputStream` will not work. Also, `llimit = sc.toString()` is pointless, as `toString()` on an `InputStreamReader` does not return anything from the stream. Beyond that, I would recommend using a more modern data file format (e.g., JSON, XML) than what your text file appears to be.

Comment: Eyad Mhanna, it is actually a fragment of code from a method inside a java class, so I guess it is not activity.

Comment: CommonsWare, can I know the full syntax, like how do I instantiate it together with the scanner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call `getAssets()` method from fragments, you need ***context*** in order to access those files. Hence, the lines causing you problems must be like this to remove the errors

```
InputStream is = getActivity().getResources.getAssets().open("socso.txt");
```

And:

```
InputStreamReader sc = new InputStreamReader(getActivity().getAssets().open("socso.txt"));
```

If you want to call these functions in a java class, create a method that you pass a parameter of type ***Context*** to it, context in an activity is the activity itself, while it is ***getActivity()*** in a fragment, so the method must be like this:

```
    public void readDoubleFromText(Context context) {
    InputStreamReader sc = new InputStreamReader(context.getAssets().open("socso.txt"));
//rest of function....
}
```

Comment: I had replace it with the first one, but it seems like it cannot resolve the 'getActivity()' part, is it because the code appear in a method in Java class?

Comment: if you are using it inside a method in a JAVA Class, you must pass a parameter of type "Context" to that method and replace getActivity() with that parameter

Comment: I see, but what should I put inside the actual parameter, like in the activity, how to I parse the context in the actual parameter?

Comment: When you call the method I posted from an activity you should pass the activity itself as the context like: readDoubleFromText(NameOfYourActivity.this); and if you want to call it from a fragment you must do like this: readDoubleFromText(getActivity());